# Differences between Minimal master page and HTML master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage

I would Like to know the brief difference between Minimal master page VS HTML master page, Please Provide any reference links.
I am New to SharePoint Development.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal master page contains only those page elements that are required by SharePoint to render the page correctly in the browser. With Design Manager, you can quickly create a minimal master page without first having to design and convert an HTML file.

If you want to design your site with more customization. you should go with HTML master page.

Here is the reference link from MS  for Minimal Master page and HTML Master Page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-convert-an-html-file-into-a-master-page-in-sharepoint

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-minimal-master-page-in-sharepoint

Comment: it can have different approaches either using SharePoint Designer or using Design Manager. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-design-manager/ this link has step by step to create a SharePoint Master page